# How to specify server region in the relay request - Unity Multiplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to specify a server to connect with using unity's new game services specifically Relay. They provide you an option for selecting the region but unfortunately I am not able to understand what value should I pass as the region string...

```
await Relay.Instance.CreateAllocationAsync(maxConnections, region);
```

There are only 4 regions as of now:

- Southeast Asia - Singapore
- West Europe - London
- East United States - North Virginia
- Central United States - Iowa

The parameter region requires a string and I have tried multiple options but they are of no use...
If anyone has anything to share, they are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct answer but I found [this](https://docs.unity.com/relay/relay-and-utp.htm) which slightly modified would allow you to simply print out all available IDs

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{ 
    // Request list of valid regions
    var regionsTask = Relay.Instance.ListRegionsAsync();

    while(!regionsTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    if (regionsTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        Debug.LogError("List regions request failed");
        yield break;
    }

    var regionList = regionsTask.Result;

   foreach(var region in regionList)
   {
       Debug.Log(region.Id);
   }
}
```

---

If unsure though the parameter `region` is **optional**. You can simply not pass it at all.

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks for reaching out!

Comment: Simply not passing the region automatically selects the region which is causing the ping to be very high, in our case the ping reaches 590ms, that is why I am trying to connect to different servers and see which will give us a better ping